# How to make my workflows run again with Automator Runner after upgrading to Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, automator

After upgrading to Mountain Lion, I cannot run my workflows with Automator Runner anymore.

The option to do that in the context menu is still there, but nothing happens, no errors, no console logs. Opening them with Automator itself and running them from there still works.

How to make my workflows run with Automator Runner after upgrading to Mountain Lion?

Comment: Seems to be a bug: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1410870

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always convert your workflows to Automator Applications if you want to be able to run them by double clicking. Open the workflow up in Automator, duplicate it, and save it with a *File Format* of **Application**, rather than the default *Workflow*:

[image: automator save dialog]

Comment: Yes, that's what I do now. And fortunately, you can still edit these workflows later.

Answer (score 0):

The renaming of iCal to Calendar might mean your events are looking for your workflows in ~/Library/Workflows/Applications/Calendar but they are still sitting in ~/Library/Workflows/Applications/iCal. Moving them got my alert workflows running again.

Comment: Ouch. That might break some things. Not in my case, though, I am not working with the Calendar. And the problem is not with the workflow itself, but with Automator Runner (works fine in Automator).